# Comparing two Strings if word spacing and capitalization do not matter-Java

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, compareto

What I want to do is create a method that takes two objects as input
of type String. The method will return logical truth if both strings are the same (word spacing and capitalization do not matter). I thought to split String, make an Array of elements, add each element to List and then compare each element to space and remove it from List. At the end use a compareToIgnoreCase() method. I stopped on removing space from List for string2. It works to string1List and doesn't work to string2List, I'm wondering why?? :(

I will be grateful for help, I spend a lot of time on it and I'm stuck. Maybe someone know a better solution.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Strings {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String string1 = "This is a first string";
    String string2 = "this is   a first string";


    String[] arrayOfString1 = string1.split("");
    List<String> string1List = new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfString1.length; ++i) {
        string1List.add(arrayOfString1[0 + i]);
    }

    String[] arrayOfString2 = string2.split("");
    List<String> string2List = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfString2.length; ++i) {
        string2List.add(arrayOfString2[0 + i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < string1List.size(); ++i) {
        String character = string1List.get(0 + i);
        if (character.equals(" ")) {
            string1List.remove(character);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < string2List.size(); ++i) {
        String character = string2List.get(0 + i);
        if (character.equals(" ")) {
            string2List.remove(character);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(string2List.size());
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "word spacing .. do not matter"? Do you consider `"a b c"` and `"a  b  c"` and `"abc"` as equal strings?

Comment: Yes, this is java teacher idea ;/

Comment: Then you can simply remove all spaces (replace them with nothing) in both strings and compare rest of letters without case sensitivity. Something like `str1.replace(" ","").equalsIgnoreCase(str2.replace(" ",""))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with spaces. You can replace them with any other character (for example "a") to test this. Therefore, removing spaces in any of the methods given above will not improve your code.

The source of the problem is iterating the list with the for command. When you remove an item from a list inside the for loop, after removing the i-th element, the next element in the list becomes the i-th current element.

On the next repetition of the loop - when i is incremented by one - the current i + 1 item becomes the next item in the list, and thus you "lose" (at least) one item. Therefore, it is a bad idea to iterate through the list with the for command.

However you may use many other methods available for collections - for instance Iterators - and your program will work fine.

```
    Iterator <String> it = string1List.iterator();
    
    while(it.hasNext())
        
    {
        if(it.next().equals("a")) it.remove();
    }
```

Of course there is no need at all to use Lists to compare these two strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below solution. As you mentioned word spacing and capitalization do not matter

1.remove capitalization - using toLowercase()
2.for word spacing -  remove all word spacing using removeAll() with regex pattern `"\\s+"` so it removes all spaces.
3. check both strings now.

```
public class StringChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(checkString("This is a first string", "this is   a first string"));
    }


    public static boolean checkString(String string1, String string2){
        String processedStr1 = string1.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        String processedStr2 = string2.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        System.out.println(" s1 : " + processedStr1);
        System.out.println(" s2 : " + processedStr2);
        return processedStr1.equals(processedStr2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that converting to lower case does not always work. For example, upper case sigma Σ will probably convert to lower case sigma σ, rather than lower-case final sigma, ς. So Σ and ς won't match, though they should: Σσς are all "the letter sigma". There are similar examples for converting to upper case.  For this reason, equalsIgnoreCase is to be preferred if "letter" can be anything other than the "A-Za-z" range.